# Weird Path in Python `pathlib` resolution that doesn't exist in system

Tags: python

I'll jump in medias res to the code:

```
from pathlib import Path
import os
p = Path(os.getenv("APPDATA")).joinpath(r"Microsoft\WindowsApps")

p.resolve()  # gives 'C:/Users/Alex/AppData/Local/Packages/PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0/LocalCache/Roaming/Microsoft/WindowsApps'
```

Why is this happening? The system says that there is no such path `p`, I check hidden files, not even a symbolic link. Why is it resolved to that path?

Comment: Is the first part `Path(os.getenv("APPDATA"))` giving you a valid path you expect?

Comment: Yes, you can check that.

Answer (score 0):

`Path.resolve()` just makes the path an absolute path, if you want to also check if the resolved path is an existing path you need to set `Path.resolve(strict=True)` or a call `.exists()` on the resolved path.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.resolve

E:

Tested this on my machine in blocks and seems to working as expected:

```
from pathlib import Path
import os

p = Path(os.getenv("APPDATA"))
print(p)
p = p.joinpath(r"Microsoft\WindowsApps")
print(p)
p = p.resolve()
print(p)
p = p.joinpath("..")
print(p)
p = p.resolve()
print(p)
```

Output:

```
C:\Users\tzane\AppData\Roaming
C:\Users\tzane\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\WindowsApps
C:\Users\tzane\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\WindowsApps
C:\Users\tzane\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\WindowsApps\..
C:\Users\tzane\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this answers my question. What you mentioned is generic, I'm referring to a specifc path that exhibits non-standard behaviour.

Comment: @AlexDeft Maybe I misunderstood, but seems to me it is working as intended. You initialize a `Path` object and then join it with another path like string, neither operation cares whether the path actually exists, only that they are valid path like strings. Resolve then only cleans up that `Path` object, such as remove any "/../". By default `.resolve()` doesn't care if the path exists on your system or not i.e. the resolved path might not exists, such as in your case.

Comment: I just managed to reproduce your results. So, apparently the black magic behaviour only happens if a virtual environment is activated. Can I ask you to please re-run your snippet in a ve?

Comment: @AlexDeft Im using conda as my venv and it gives the same results. Could you add your VE config to the question body?